# Navigate to a xaml page from the isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, navigation, isolatedstorage

I would like to know if anyone has done this before or tried to do it. I would like to navigate from my current page to a page generated and stored on the isolated storage.

Is that possible?

I already found a way of generating the xaml code and I'm working on generating the xaml.cs file but I can't seem to find a way of navigating to the newly created and existing file in the isolated storage.
I am using the "isostore" URI schema but it throws an exception in RootFrame_NavigationFailed:
[System.InvalidOperationException] = {"No XAML was found at the location '/isostore;/screenTest.xaml'."} . Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Cipri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
}

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string UserName;

    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue<string>("UserName", out UserName);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserName))
    {
        txtUserName.Text = UserName;
        txtPassword.Focus();
    }

    else
        txtUserName.Focus();
}

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["UserName"] = txtUserName.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest you can get is:

- Store usercontrols (rather than pages) in the isolated storage
- Load them using `XamlReader.Load`
- Inject the loaded UserControl inside of the current page

Drawbacks:

- You can forget about the code-behind file as you can't compile it. You'll have to find another way to wire-up the events. I suggest taking a MVVM approach, by binding actions and using the same viewmodel for every usercontrol
- You're not using the NavigationService, so you have to handle the navigation stuff (back button and application resuming after tombstoning)

Comment: This is my current approach. I was trying to re-factorize everything in order to be able to use the default navigation system. The problem with this approach is that when using controls like DatePicker which by default navigates to the datePickerPage it may become very annoying when you come back from that page. Even if I restore the last state I can't interact with the page. Thank you for your help, I will try more with this then. :)